# undefined method `model_name' for Project:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've looked through all the related questions but nothing's new for me here.

I have a Project controller with "new" action

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @newproject = Project.new
  end
end
```

Project is a simple class, not active record:

```
class Project
  attr_accessor :name, :description
  def initialize
    @name = ""
    @description = ""
  end
end
```

I get the error "undefined method `model_name' for Project:Class"

This is an erb file sample:

```
<%= form_tag(@newproject)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :description %><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

if Project is not an active record subclass, you need these and you can use `form_for`

```
class Project
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  def persisted?
    false
  end
  ...
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for(@newproject)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :description %><br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: Viktor, thanks a lot! It helped me. I just stuck on this. Perhaps, this is not the best way to create temporary instance to give out, so that user could create a real active record Project.

Comment: Indeed, if you ever persist Project, do not use this, use class Project < ActiveRecord::Base but do not override initialize.

Comment: Thanks, great help.@ViktorTrón any pointers how to get more familiar with knowing Rails to extent that you can debug this issue?

Answer (score 3):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Comment: In this case I get "Could not find table 'projects'"

Comment: I just want to create a temp Project instance so that a user at client side could edit new parameters to create a valid Project instance on the server side

Comment: oh in that case, just use the ActiveRecord persisted class's new object in the form. It is temporary, since you don't save it. If your class is never persisted, see my response.

Comment: If you don't want a a actual database behind your class,  but still want to use it in a form,  you need to check out this rails cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Comment: Viktor, good point, temporary Project class now seems to me redundant here. That is temporary active record Project looks like the better solution here.

Answer (score 3):

just for the record - here is the Railscast for that issue:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue because my class wasn't using ActiveRecord; adding the following to my class solved it: `include ActiveModel::Model`