# undefined method `model_name' for User:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Below is my `form`.

```
<%= form_for @user, {class: "form-horizontal", id: "signupform"} do |f| %>    
<% end %>
```

Below is my `PersonController`

```
class PersonController < ApplicationController
  def new
      @user = User.new
  end    
end
```

When i try to navigate to `http://localhost:3000/person/new`, i get the following error below.

```
undefined method `model_name' for User:Class
```

User Model

```
class User << CustomService 
  verbose true

  get :all, '/users/'
  post :login, '/signin'

end
```

Comment: Could you also post the code of your `User` model

Comment: @rkon: updated the user model class.

Comment: There is some clue for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823736/undefined-method-model-name-for-projectclass?rq=1

Comment: If you google "undefined method `model_name'" you will come across multiple questions about that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't want to specify @user, instead just use symbol(:user). Please try it.

Your code should be something like this,

```
<%= form_for :user, url: users_path, method: :post, {class: "form-horizontal", id: "signupform"} do |f| %>    
<% end %>
```

note: users_path => your post path.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: Why use symbol?, can u explain a bit more on this.

Comment: theJva: we have lot of ways to create form for an object, a)you can specify the object like @user, so all the required parameters as etracted from that specified object like action, method, etc... b)you can specify the form for a symbole like :user, then you need to specify the url, method.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your User class is not inherinting from ActiveRecord::Base, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 #your attributes and methods
end
```

Try to inherit User from this base class.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`User` class is not an [`ActiveRecord model`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) in your code. Therefore, when you create `User.new`, it's just returning the naked ruby class (which doesn't work with Rails)

Check `Rudy Sidinger`'s answer for how to do this correctly

---

Further, you may wish to look at this part of your class:

```
  get :all, '/users/'
  post :login, '/signin'
```

Why are you defining routes in your model? I've only ever defined routes in the `config/routes.rb` file like so:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: :index, path_names: { index: "all" } do #-> routes to /all for users idnex
    collection do
        post "signin", action: :login 
    end
end
```