# undefined method `model_name' for Address:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am not using ActiveRecord as an ORM in my application, but Perpetuity gem by jgaskins (https://github.com/jgaskins/perpetuity). I get the error 'undefined method 'model_name for Address:Class, when I try to display the address#index page. 
This is my model

```
 class Address
   attr_accessor :city, :county, :line1, :line2, :postcode
 end
```

My controller:

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @addresses = Perpetuity[Address].all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @addresses }
    end
  end

  def show
    @address = Perpetuity[Address].find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @address }
    end
  end
  def new
    @address = Address.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @address }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @address = Perpetuity[Address].find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @address = Address.new(params[:address])
    Perpetuity[Address].insert @address

    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.save
        format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Address was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @address, status: :created, location: @address }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @address = Perpetuity[Address].find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.update_attributes(params[:address])
        format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Address was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 def destroy
   @address = Perpetuity[Address].find(params[:id])
   Perpetuity[Address].delete @address

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to addresses_url }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
 end
end
```

The addresses/index.html.erb file

## Listing addresses

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Line1</th>
    <th>Line2</th>
    <th>Postcode</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>County</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @addresses.each do |address| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= address.line1 %></td>
    <td><%= address.line2 %></td>
    <td><%= address.postcode %></td>
    <td><%= address.city %></td>
    <td><%= address.county %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', address %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_address_path(address) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', address, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Address', new_address_path, class: "tiny button radius" %>
```

I have tried different solutions described on stackoverflow including adding the following code to the controller ([undefined method `model_name' for Project:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823736/undefined-method-model-name-for-projectclass)):

```
 extend ActiveModel::Naming
 include ActiveModel::Conversion
 def persisted?
   false
 end
```

This however results in another error like this:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"addresses", :id=>#<Address:0x52f8df8 @id="23983a22-2603-4f9b-a8b6-9fe3e53eba39", @line1=nil, @line2=nil, @postcode=nil, @city="Budapest", @county=nil, @created_at=nil, @updated_at=nil>}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

For some the entire object is read as id. Does anyone know how to get this working? Thank you.

Comment: What is this `Perpetuity[Address]` mean?

Comment: @Pavan as she has stated in ques, she is not using Rails `ActiveRecord` ORM, instead she is using `perpetuity` which is a data mapper.

Comment: This is how perpetuity accesses the "Address" table. This is a simple explanation how the gem is implemented int he app. https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/2014/01/14/data-mapper-pattern-rails-perpetuity-gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Perpetuity` README docs "you have to include ActiveModel::Model in your objects that you want to pass to various Rails methods (such as redirect_to, form_for and render)."

Try this and it should work as expected:

```
class Address
 attr_accessor :city, :county, :line1, :line2, :postcode
 include Perpetuity::RailsModel
end
```

Again from the README "This will let Rails know how to talk to your models in the way that Perpetuity handles them."

`model_name` is an `ActiveModel` method so without including this you will be unable to access these methods properly and trust me many rails gems use `model_name` to handle situations pertaining to routing.

**Update**

This is based on the question the comments about the `errors` method

I do not see an `errors` method anywhere in `Perpetuiy`. I think you would have to implement your own structure for this.

Also `save` will not return `false` ever it just updates the attributes without validation so you may have to rethink your design.

Actually looking at the change log validations were completely removed in 1.0.0.0beta

Like you said you included `ActiveModel::Errors` which you could possibly handle like this.

```
def errors
  @errors ||= ActiveModel::Errors.new(self) 
end 

def save 
  validate! 
  errors.empty? ? super : false
end 

def validate!
 #place custom validations here e.g.
 errors.add(:name, "cannot be blank.") if self.name = ""
 errors.add(:number,"must be less than 7.") if self.number >= 7
end
```

Please note custom validations will not be standard Rails validations since these are not included either and if you keep moving down the inclusion path pretty soon you'll end up back at `ActiveRecord`

Also Note I do not and have not used Perpetuity so these are guidelines and I make no representation that they will work 100% correctly

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work except for when I try to edit an object I get NoMethodError in Addresses#edit (undefined method `errors' for #<Address:0x4d19b88>) pointing to the standard line 2 created by rails in adresses/edit.html.erb: 
2:     <% if @address.errors.any? %>

Comment: @evoo I have no experience with `Perpetuity` at all. I just read the docs page and realized what your initial issue was. I will see what I can find

Comment: @evoo see Update to long for comment

Comment: Engineersmnky thanks for this. Stepping out of the ActiveRecord zone is definitely a challenge for me. I found and added this to my model [link]http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html but no I get undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass as if @addresses.errors was nil and not actually an empty array.

Comment: @evoo have you initialized errors? `any?` is not a method if you look at the link you posted. you could use `unless @address.errors.empty?` or use `if @address.errors.to_a.any?`. Yes breaking out of the ActiveRecord zone we have all become accustomed to can be very difficult.