# NoMethodError in Articles#new undefined method `model_name' for #<Article:0x000000035a3450>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I am having a problem while creating articles from the UI.

My task is to make a new page with "create an article" shown on the page and text fields with title and  description and submit button when I press the submit button the article I typed in should be saved and when I go to the page where the articles are saved they should be there.

Error log:

[image: this is my image of the error while I was running the app]

This is my Cloud 9 code

`routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# root 'welcome#index'
resources :articles

root 'pages#home'
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
```

Articles controller (`articles_controller.rb`):

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new 
  end
end
```

`new.html.erb` in articles folder in views:

```
<h1>Create an article</h1>
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Article model (`article.rb`) :

```
class Article 

end
```

Comment: Did you try google out the error at first ? This might help you: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823736/undefined-method-model-name-for-projectclass

Comment: you also will need to add fields to your form,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `Article` model a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` (`ApplicationRecord` from Rails 5.x)?

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Comment: well i dont know what you mean in my articles_controller.rb file i have this : class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   
   def new
     @article = Article.new 
   end
    
    
     
     
    
end 

 and in my article.rb file i have this : class Article 

end

Comment: Nope, I mean in your `article.rb`, your model

Comment: if i try that in my article.rb file i get this error :Could not find table 'articles'

Extracted source (around line #4):
2
3 def new
4@article = Article.new 
5   end
6
7

Comment: Have you a migration for the articles table?

Comment: no i havent should i type in rake db:migrate in the terminal

Comment: First you need a migration file for article, then you can run rake db:migrate to create the table

Comment: well how do i make a migration file i haven't been taught that yet

Comment: `rails generate migration CreateArticles` but you need to read about migrations, I cannot teach you rails here

Comment: We are going off topic here, open another question with related code